# How Can I transfer data through internet from client to server using .NET?

Tags: networking, client-server

I am developing a server client application, where Client will send a huge amount of data to server through internet. However I have done some asynchronous socket programing before. Can I use same code here ?

Answer (score 4):

If both sides are .NET there are many higher level options like [Windows Communication Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation).

- [Microsoft portal on WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)
- [WCF samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730936.aspx)

But you can use bare metal sockets if you want to.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please elaborate WCF little more.(never heard about it)

Comment: WCF is Windows Communcation Foundation and a very big subject by itself. I'll add some links to the post.

Comment: if I use simple socket, is there any possibilities of data lost ?

Comment: If you use TCP NO. If  you use UDP YES.

Answer (score 0):

[**Helpful Code Examples**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/CatalogNetwork.htm)

If you want to do low level stuff like sockets [**C# Netwrok Programming by Richard Blum**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782141765)
 is probably the best book.

Also,
[Asynchronous TCP server in C#](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/AsyncTcpServer.htm) and [Asynchronous TCP client in C#](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/AsyncTcpClient.htm).

Code samples from [**Essential WCF: For .NET Framework 3.5**](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321440064).